# rails routing nested resources duplicate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to support:

```
POST images/1/comments/2/like
```

and

```
POST comments/2/like
```

They both point to same resources with same action. How can I do that in rails route file?

```
  resources :images do
    resources :comments do
      member do
        post 'like'
      end
    end
  end
```

This will work for

```
POST images/1/comments/2/like
```

but how can I also for when I don't specify the `images/1` part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider reworking which RESTful routes for `Comment` you're nesting, and which you're not. I'm assuming your models look something like this:

```
# app/models/image.rb
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :comments
end

# app/models/comment.rb
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :image
end
```

Because your `Image` and `Comment` models possess a one-to-many relationship, I can see why you'd think to nest the comments resource route within the images one. However, of all the CRUD actions in `comments_controller.rb`, *only **`create`***  actually requires that a parent image ID be explicitly passed in. From a RESTful perspective, only the `new` and `create` actions require that a `image_id` is passed to the action. The `edit`, `update`, `delete`, and `like` actions can all take place independently of the parent image.

Consider the alternative routing schematic instead:

```
# config/routes.rb
resources :images do
  resources :comments, :only => [:index, :new, :create]
end

resources :comments, :only => [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy] do
  member do
    post 'like'
  end
end
```

Now, only the comment actions *that are explicitly depended on a parent ID* are actually nested within the images routes. The remainder of the comment actions are directly routed to the comments controller without passing in the parent ID. Your routes are no longer duplicated, and each action will have exactly one route declared for it.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response/explanation!

Comment: Surely. Hope it all makes sense. Basically, ensuring that each action has just one route keeps your application DRY and keeps you from needing to add a bunch of conditionals to process parameters within actions that are routed to from multiple sources.

Comment: This is kind of late but....is it common to have the path of index/new/create of comments resources not include the image's id but rather include it in params? so rather than saying images/1/comments, do comments/1?image_id=5 . Which one is more restful ? Thanks!

Comment: Either are acceptable, though Rails convention is to have friendly URLs. To benefits come to mind: first, they are more semantic, and second, search engines have an easier time indexing them. But it's up to you how to do this. Of course, Rails generates friendly URLs by default, so from an easy-of-use standpoint, it may be easier just to stick with convention than abstract a new way of mapping URLs.

Comment: Thanks, but which one you are referring to when you say 'they'? Is it ' images/1/comments' ?

Comment: Exactly, `image/1/comments`.

Answer (score 2):

You can make it more beautiful actually. According to http://ruby-journal.com/how-to-dry-your-rails-routes/, this also works:

```
comments = Proc.new do
  member do
    post 'like'
  end
end

resources :comments, &comments

resources :images do
  comments.call
end
```

and in Rails 4 you could use concerns

```
concern :comments_concern do
  member do
    post 'like'
  end
end

resources :comments, concerns: :comments_concern

resources :images, concerns: :comments_concern do
  #do more stuff here
end
```

I didn't test this, but it might help. Have a look at the website mentioned. Good luck

-frbl

Answer (score 0):

simply add `resources :images` it may work

Answer (score 0):

Not sure there is a much more beautiful way than repeating this below:

```
resources :comments do
  member do
    post 'like'
  end
end
```

Like so:

```
resources :images do
  resources :comments do
    member do
      post 'like'
    end
  end
end

resources :comments do
  member do
    post 'like'
  end
end
```